# TFS 2019 - Test cases were deleted by mistake - how can we reproduce them

Tags: tfs

Accidently we have deleted a test suite ( we have the suite ID) of Test cases.

How can we reproduce them?

Thanks  in advance,
Ela

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/delete-test-artifacts?view=azure-devops):

> We only support permanent deletion of test artifacts such as test
>
> plans, test suites, test cases, shared steps and shared parameters.
>
> Deleted test artifacts won't appear in the recycle bin and cannot be
>
> restored.
> Thus the deleted test artifacts will be permanently deleted.

The only solution here is **restoring** your DETACHED (this is required) team project **collection database from a backup**.

Hope you’re totally taking nightly backups. You lose a little data depending on how old that backup is, but it may be more important to get back your test cases than have to redo a few hours of work.